# How do I query for a string in MongoDB's Simple REST interface?

Tags: mongodb, rest

MongoDB provides a simple REST interface in order for you to send simple queries. The problem is, I don't know how to specify the type when querying. For instance:

Say I have this document in the collection,

```
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51ae1042c92ba30ae0afa26f" }, "serialNumber" : "4661016803", "clientPayload" : { "$binary" : "gwVGYQFoAwEBAQJJkFGj839Ro/N/GcfKG8l89gcAAHvNAAAAAAFDCwADAv+lLwkfAAEACAAAPqQHAAAw7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==", "$type" : "00" }, "receiveTime" : { "$date" : 1369717200070 } }
```

How would I run a query on the serialNumber?

I'm trying

```
http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/test/stuff/?filter_serialNumber=4661016803
```

But apparently it's running a query for  `"query" : { "serialNumber" : 4661016803 }`

I want `"query" : { "serialNumber" : "4661016803" }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far i as know, you can't specify the type of value. 
This seems like a bug or limitations. 
If the requested value starts with a digit, it will be interpreted as a number, not as a string.

As example: "abc" -> "abc", "1abc" -> 1, "123" - 123.

**UPDATE**: 
I looked up the source, 
\mongodb-src-r2.4.4\src\mongo\db\restapi.cpp:

```
BSONElement e = i.next();
string name = e.fieldName();
if ( ! name.find( "filter_" ) == 0 )
    continue;

string field = name.substr(7);
const char * val = e.valuestr();

char * temp;

// TODO: this is how i guess if something is a number.  pretty lame right now
double number = strtod( val , &temp );
if ( temp != val )
    queryBuilder.append( field , number );
else
    queryBuilder.append( field , val );
}
```

Look at the TODO comment and `strtod` function - this is the bug.